# Latex Table alignment error for IEEE publication

Tags: tables, ieeetran

Hello I am trying to fit a table into half column for a IEEE paper. In order to replicate the problem I prepared a small example:

This is the **incorrect behavior**, notice the spaces are not properly aligned and the interruption of the line at the end of the table and that the header should all be centered :

[image]

Below the correct behavior I am looking for with no extra space, `\midrule` with no interruption an all headers are centered:

[image]

I checked several times the format of the tables and I can't see the reason of the extra space problem and the interruption of the `\midrule`.
So far is what I have:

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage{siunitx} % consider is v3

% Some paragraphs...

\begin{table*}[ht]
\centering
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X c !{\qquad}Xc!{\qquad}Xc}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Most prolific scholar related to QUERY-1} \\
    \cmidrule(r{1.8em}){1-6}
    Journal & TP (\%) & TC & CiteScore 2020 & The most article & Time cited \\
    \midrule
     \emph{Ultrasound In Obstetrics And Gynecology} & 175 & 5606 & 9.8 & Maternal and perinatal outcomes of pregnant women with SARS-CoV-2 infection & 28 \\
    
     \emph{Human Reproduction} & 205 & 6876 & 10.2 & Development of an artificial intelligence-based assessment model for prediction of embryo viability using static images captured by optical light microscopy during IVF & 22 \\

    \emph{Medical Physics} & 359 & 10043 & 6.1 & Breast tumor segmentation in 3D automatic breast ultrasound using Mask scoring R-CNN & 14 \\

    \emph{Medical Image Analysis} & 251 & 6794 & 24.2 & Deep neural network models for computational histopathology: A survey & 14 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
```

**EDIT TO QUESTION**

In addition to that I have a very strange behavior I just noticed related to the title of the table. As soon as I make the title longer it pushes everything on the right causing the strange effect below:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X c !{\qquad}Xc!{\qquad}Xc}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Top 10 most cited journals with their most cited article related to QUERY-1} \\
```

[image]

Posts that I consulted to help me find a solutions are [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295385/tabularx-alignment-error), [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602656/ieee-has-formatting-problem-for-table) and I also came across [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515047/fit-table-into-one-column-for-ieee) very useful source and applied part of this solution which brought me very close to the final solution of the table I am looking for. All helpful but still couldn't understand the formatting issue I have.

There must be something that I am not catching properly, please point in the right direction for finding a solution.

Comment: you specified `!{\qquad}X` which adds 2em extra space and then says the 4th column should be stretched as wide as needed to force the table to be full page width. As it is a numeric column you could use `r` or a decimal alignment column such as `S` from `siunitx`

Comment: Thanks for your comment and for stopping by! Gotcha! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- your MWE is not compilable ... missed are `\begin{document}`, etc
- you define table layout so, that has big empty space between some columns and use `\cmidrule(r{1.8em}){1-6}` instead of simple `\midrule`
- I suspect, that you like to have table of the following format:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % new
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, 
            tabularx}  % added
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}%
                     \hsize=#1\hsize}X} % new
\usepackage{siunitx} % consider is v3

\begin{document} % added

\begin{table*}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\itshape}L{0.9}cc cL{1.1}c}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{2}{@{} l}{Most prolific scholar related to QUERY-1} \\
    \midrule
\normalfont{Journal} 
    & TP (\%) & TC & \makecell{CiteScore\\ 2020} & The most article & \makecell{Time\\ cited} \\
    \midrule
Ultrasound In Obstetrics And Gynecology
    & 175 & 5606 & 9.8 & Maternal and perinatal outcomes of pregnant women with SARS-CoV-2 infection & 28 \\

Human Reproduction 
    & 205 & 6876 & 10.2 & Development of an artificial intelligence-based assessment model for prediction of embryo viability using static images captured by optical light microscopy during IVF & 22 \\

Medical Physics
    & 359 & 10043 & 6.1 & Breast tumor segmentation in 3D automatic breast ultrasound using Mask scoring R-CNN & 14 \\

Medical Image Analysis 
    & 251 & 6794 & 24.2 & Deep neural network models for computational histopathology: A survey & 14 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your time in helping out! It works and yes that is the format I am looking for.